# Connecting fail when connect to the Google Api Client

Tags: java, android, google-api, android-service

I try connecting to the Google API Client to achieve some functionality in my application. But for some reason I cannot connect to the Google API Client And because that I can not continue to use Google services.

After I initialize the GoogleApiClient I check if `mGoogleApiClient.isConnected` and always get it False and I don't know why. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

**Notice that everything happens on background service.**

```
public class Background extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<Status> {

private String TAG = "Background";

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    Log.e(TAG,"Start");


    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.e(TAG,"GoogleApiClient not yet connected");
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG,"GoogleApiClient connected");

    }

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Connection failed. Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

}

@Override
public void onResult(Status status) {
    if (status.isSuccess()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Successfully added activity detection.");

    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + status.getStatusMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connected");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the googleApiClient in `onStartCommand` of your service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


Log.e(TAG,"Start");


mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();

  if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
    Log.e(TAG,"GoogleApiClient not yet connected");

    mGoogleApiClient.connect(); // connect it here..

  } else {
    Log.e(TAG,"GoogleApiClient connected");

}

return Service.START_STICKY;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not calling .connect() in the right place. You are building a client, and you must call .connect() after that. You are immediately checking if it is connected, which it will never be.

Please add .connect() after .build() in .onStartCommand() and remove this code:

```
if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
    Log.e(TAG,"GoogleApiClient not yet connected");
} else {
    Log.e(TAG,"GoogleApiClient connected");
}
```

Also, remove this since it might get you in an unwanted state:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connected");
    // remove this -> mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```